# Not auto-starting webapp without servlet

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, servlets

I have a simple webapp deployed within Apache Tomcat (7.0.x) which is bootstrapped using a ContextLoaderListener instead of a Servlet. I would like this webapp to NOT auto-start whenever the Tomcat server itself is started but instead only started/stopped manually via the Tomcat manager. The examples I see online show how this can easily be done with the following code for servlets within web.xml:

```
<servlet><load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup></servlet>
```

But no examples are available for when using a ContextLoaderListener. Is this possible at all? Or would I need to include a servlet in order to configure the webapp to NOT auto-start whenever the Tomcat server itself is started?

Thanks in advance,
PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this recent discussion on the Tomcat users' list which I believe answers your exact question: http://markmail.org/message/5hp3dohwj3vncg4c

The bottom line is that you can start only the Manager webapp on startup, but there are some restrictions about what happens after a restart. The replies from Mark Thomas are the most useful.

Comment: Hi @Christopher Schultz, thanks for the thread link you provided which I think it does answer the question pretty much. It makes me wonder however why there is no simple attribute option available for app contexts to set deployments to NOT start when the container is started! Thanks again, PM.

Comment: There's no difference between starting Tomcat without your webapp and starting Tomcat with your webapp but not starting it. If you don't want to start your webapp, don't put it into the deployment directory. If you need to do something like manually-start webapps after a Tomcat start, then use the manager webapp: that's what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to do this in web.xml. `load-on-startup` is used to tell the webapp to start a servlet when the webapp is started. A webapp often consists of multiple servlets.

If you want to make sure the webapp is not loaded at startup, and instead use Tomcat manager to start it, I suggest you set `deployOnStartup="false"` in the `<Host>` container, in `settings.xml`. See the Tomcat 7 documentation page for the details:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html

Comment: Hello @reidarok, thanks for the quick reply. In my case, I do want the webapp to be deployed (i.e. WAR file unpacked, etc.) but I do not want the app itself started (i.e. running). That is, I want the web app deployed but not set to start running when Tomcat is started up. And then only started when clicking Start command button in Tomcat's web application management page. Is this possible at all? Thanks again, PM.