# Starting Tomcat with all webapps stopped

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a test Tomcat 7 server with many webapps that should be available there, but they are not all needed at the same time.
On startup, Tomcat starts every deployed webapp, but I guess it can be told to just start the server, or maybe only a few specific webapps like `/manager` ?

If read about `deployOnStartup`, but that is about deploying, and not about starting them.

Comment: It probably won't be easy. See this existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602163/not-auto-starting-webapp-without-servlet . Its not a recent question, but I don't think anything has changed since then.